# I use MainCamera`ray to get the GameObject collided,but if the GameObject is Image,I can not collide the Iamge,What can I do?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.name.StartsWith("Image"))
        {//can not get image
            Debug.Log("OK");
            image = GameObject.Find(hit.collider.name).gameObject;
            Debug.Log ("image.name:"+image.name);
        }
    }
```

The code to get collision.

If the ray to the Image,I can not get collision event.

How can I get the Image collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If image is a [UI Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html). You can use [Event System's raycast](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/821590/unity-46-how-to-raycast-against-ugui-objects-from.html).
Or If by Image you mean a 2D object with sprite renderer attached to it. you need to have a Box collider attached to it.

And by the way `image = GameObject.Find(hit.collider.name).gameObject;` is wrong.you can get gameObject like this : `image = hit.collider.gameObject;`

Comment: Thank you,it works.And another question,I want to use gaze(a point center on my android phone)to get the Image info,you know how?

Comment: Do you know how to use gaze point to get the collided image info?

Comment: which platform are you working on? Google Cardboard or Oculus Gear VR

Comment: A thire part platform with no gaze,so I need to implement the gaze by my self.

Comment: Which SDK? does it have any name?

Comment: A Chinese company here:http://dev.inibiru.com/download.jsp .And I had find the way to use gaze like:http://talesfromtherift.com/gaze-fuse-buttons-in-unity